# is it good practice to use multiple header files in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In few wordpress themes i find that developers use more than one header files. Some sites have minor design changes in header for different pages. So is it a good practice to use more than one header in wordpress theme.

What is best wordpress standard coding to be used in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you can make any spaghetti code as WordPress is all of it.

I would prefer to have 1 general header and lots of unique. Each of them includes general header at start and then consists of its unique code.

If you don't have similar lines you don't include general.

Either way if you need other header then you just need to create one. I don't see reason to worry.

Better think if you need custom header code